# How to make epaper(Online News Paper) like application in .net 

Tags: asp.net, winforms, image-processing, slice

Let say I have complete Image of Newspaper front page i want it make asp.net or winform application so user can slice this page and then link this page to another image...

I am confused what should i do from where should I start although this is not my newspaper application its university project but it works same like this images....

For clear understanding here is site link eg. http://epaper.dawn.com

can you give some reference links, sample project or blogs for this solution.

Comment: Have you had any luck implementing the solution?
I'm in the same boat and ended up developing myself. Just started thlough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the user draw rectangles over content areas and assign them a label or link, then you would store these rectangles as keys in a dictionary, with the associated value being the assigned label or hyperlink.

Then when the user moves the mouse or clicks somewhere, check all of the rectangles to see if the mouse is inside any of them, and find the associated item (be it a label or hyperlink)

That's just a ballpark idea, hope it helps.

I'm not sure this is image processing though, as really the user is slicing the newspaper up, not the computer.